# Traverse the ArrayList and display at least 3 elements from the list, before new line

Tags: java

I am trying to display at least 3 elements from my ArrayList before printing new line, where the next line will also print out 3 elements and so on. (Hence, each row will print 3 elements)

Here's my current code

```
System.out.println("List of Student IDs:");

for (Student s : studentList) {
   System.out.println(s.getStudentId());
```

I've also tried

```
String format = "%-5s %-5s %s %n";
for (Student s : studentList) {
   System.out.printf(format, s.getStudentId());
```

But since the StudentID will only be retrieved after each traversal, there will be null error for the String format.

In summary, what I want is:

```
List of Student IDs:
8   3   1   
4   7   9
10  12
```

But now it can only print

```
List of Student IDs:
8
3
1
4
7
9
10
12
```

Comment: Don't try to find a magic sinlge line that will do it. Try to think about a logical strategy. Hint: use indices and basic arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the first approach, `System.out.println(s.getStudentId());` would always print a new line after printing the `s.getStudentId()`. Therefore you should use `System.out.print()` instead.

Here's a simple sample:

```
`int index = 0;
 for (Student s : studentList) {
   System.out.print(s.getStudentId()+"\t");
   index++;
   if(index%3==0)
     System.out.println();
 }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, by making use of the modulo operator `%` we determine whether to print out a new line or not.

```
int i = 1;
for (Student s : stud) {
    System.out.printf("%3d", s.getId());
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    i++;
}
```

If `i` is exactly divisible by 3 a new line is printed else data is printed on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

We can use an `Iterator` and check the `Iterator.hasNext()` to determine if there is a next element, else print an empty string:

```
for (Iterator<Student> itr = studentList.listIterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
       System.out.print(getNext(itr) + "  " + getNext(itr) + "  "+ getNext(itr));
       System.out.println();
 }
```

The `getNext()` will check if there is a next element else it will return empty string `""`.

```
public String getNext(Iterator<Student> itr){
       return itr.hasNext() ? String.valueOf(itr.next().getStudentId()) : "";
}
```